# How to pass SQL query from Excel/vba which contains another query as string

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm using Excel/vba to send query to SQL Server. The query is something like:

```
using database

declare @queryString as nvarchar(max)

create table #tempTable (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)

insert into #tempTable
    select top 10 col1, col2, col3 
    from sometable 

set @queryString='select * from #tempTable where col1>10'
exec(@queryString);
```

If I run this query in SQL Server Management Studio, I get the desired results, but when I run it from Excel/vba, I get an error

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

I tried to pass it to SQL Server Management Studio like this (where `queryExample` is my query):

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Connection.ConnectionString = "... connection string ..."
Connection.Open
With rs
    .ActiveConnection=Connection
    .Open queryExample
End With
```

and like this

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
cmd.CommandText = queryExample
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = Connection
Set rsSR = cmd.Execute
```

but nothing is working, and I always get the same error. I think that problem is in `exec()` function, because if I pass query like this:

```
select top 10 col1, col2, col3 from sometable
```

I don't get any error and recordset is populated with data.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I made a mistake when copying vba code for the last example to pass the query to SQL Server Management Studio, the actual code was:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Connection.ConnectionString = "... connection string ..."
Connection.Open
cmd.CommandText = queryExample
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = Connection
Set rsSR = cmd.Execute
```

Conection was opened in both cases - value of .State of Connection object was 1.

Comment: Your db connection is not open...that's what the error is telling you...open the connection first, then execute the query

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment, I made a mistake when copying code in my question, I posted edited version... Db connection is opened in both cases since value of .State of db connection object is 1, and simple queries with just `select` and `from ` are executed corectly and recordset is populated with data as expected.